# fread returning zero when not eof

Tags: c

I am using this code to read 2 12 bit numbers from a file. For some reason, it returns -1 before the end of the file. It occurs in the same spot for every file, around 1/2 way through. I'm thinking fread is interpereting end of file early but not sure. The 3rd case for low8 is where it returns zero.

```
int read12(FILE *infil)
{
 static int number1 = -1, number2 = -1;
 unsigned char hi8, lo4hi4, lo8;
 int retval;

 if(number2 != -1)                        
    {                                    
     retval = number2;                    
     number2 = -1;                                        
    }
 else                                     
    {
     if(fread(&hi8, 1, 1, infil) != 1)  
        return(-1);

     if(fread(&lo4hi4, 1, 1, infil) != 1)
        return(-1);

     if(fread(&lo8, 1, 1, infil) != 1)     
       return(-1);


     number1 = hi8 * 0x10;                
     number1 = number1 + (lo4hi4 / 0x10); 
     number2 = (lo4hi4 % 0x10) * 0x0100;  

     number2 = number2 + lo8;            

     retval = number1;
    }

 return(retval);
}
```

Comment: Is this running on a Windows platform?  Can you show how you `fopen()` the file?

Comment: can you add a `perror()` in the failure case?

Comment: Try returning different values at each failure point so you can analyse the reason. Or step the code with a debugger.

Comment: Are you opening it with `fopen(..., "rb");` note the `r` and the `b` (read binary) flags?

Comment: i'm opening the file with FILE *in = fopen(argv[1],"r"). I tried "rb" and i got a strange output

Comment: Please read the fread documentation. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Kirningham & Ritchie’s book (the inventor of C) and I found this:
« size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nobj, FILE *stream)
fread reads from stream into the array ptr at most nobj objects of size size. fread returns the number of objects read; this may be less than the number requested »

I think that the problem comes from you « if »
Try to change you condition in your if, maybe it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `fread()` is really the best bet here: `fgetc()` is designed to read exactly one character at time, and I think the algorithm itself could be made a lot clearer.

The idea is keeping track of any pending 4 bits (a nibble) from call to call, assembling the full 12-bit response from whatever combination of two bytes needed.

Code assumes the upper 4 bits is part of the previous byte, and the lower 4 bits is part of the *next* byte.

```
int read12(FILE *infil)
{
  static int byte_is_pending = FALSE;
  static unsigned char byte;

  int c; // needs to be signed to detect EOF

  if (byte_is_pending)
  {
    int hi_part = (byte & 0x0F) << 8;

    byte_is_pending = FALSE;

    if ( (c = fgetc(infil)) == EOF) return -1;

    return hi_part | (c & 0xFF);
  }
  else
  {
    if ( (c = fgetc(infil)) == EOF) return -1;

    byte_is_pending = TRUE;

    int hi_part = (c & 0xFF) << 4;

    if ( (c = fgetc(infil)) == EOF) return -1;

    byte = c;

    return hi_part | ((byte >> 4) & 0x0F );
  }
}
```

(Code compiles, but has not been tested).

This does not weigh into the early EOF you're getting, but as has been noted, it's not clear that the static variables you're using are being managed properly from call to call.